# Remove div if webkit scollbars are supported

Tags: css, webkit, scrollbar

I am using a custom scrollbar for webkit browsers. The thing is that when the browser supports webkit. I want it to remove the border I have around the entire body. 
I got it to work by using `-webkit-box-sizing` on the right div and a negative margin value as you can see in the fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/Yfw49/1/

And it works really great except for browsers that supports box-sizing but not webkit scrollbars. For example mobile browsers that don't have scrollbars at all.

Is there a way to make it work? I tried a jQuery method that asked if the browser supported webkit, and if so, remove the div. But that made the div appear for a short while and then removed it. It looked bad.

Please have a look at the jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/Yfw49/1/

(I know I could make the markup cleaner without all the elements. But let's focus on the other problem)

Comment: Where did you run the jQuery method? The soonest you can run it is at the beginning of on DOM ready (`$(document).ready(function() {})`). If it still happens then and the "flicker" is not acceptable, you'll have to use CSS, likely through media queries to differentiate browsers.

Comment: I tried it high up in the head section. Right after the css.